# Serialization of custom objects in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

ASP .NET WEB API newbie question.

I've a silly web api project where there is no model, just a single controller with a get method.

The get method retrieves data from an external database using a proprietary object model APIs.

```
public class MyObjectController : ApiController
{

    private static IList<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();


    private MyObjectCollection GetData()
    {
            return MyExternalDB.Query();
    }

    // GET api/myobjects
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get()
    {
        MyObjectCollection objcoll = GetData();
        IList<MyObject> list = objcoll.Cast<MyObject>().ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Now, the project builds without errors, but when I try to debug via IE url api/myobjects and download results to json, the IE fails saying "file cannot be downloaded".

I'm suspecting that the object is not correctly serialized to json. Using the package Web Api Tracing I can see the following exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Project' with type ...
```

**Questions**

- MyObject does not rely on a model and is based on a custom type defined in a separate API. Should I expect the serializer to work fine and convert my object to json (assuming no sel-referencing loop issue)?
- How should I handle MyObject getting rid of self-referencing properties so that it can be correctly serialized to a json response?

Comment: _"I'm suspecting that the object is not correctly serialized to json"_ - or, you're using the wrong tool to test an API with. Try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) instead of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```

to your `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` class

That should force it, but as commented you really should be testing your API by creating a proper request.  There are a few tools:

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) (Chrome plugin) 
[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

As your applications are probably going to create a request and specify data type and handle it so you need to simulate that with one of the above tools.

Comment: I stopped using the 2 you mention (well, fiddler will still be useful for other purposes) after coming across google's Advanced REST Client.

Comment: Sweet, i'll give that a shot!